# How to use vimgrep to grep the word that's highlighted by Vim?

Tags: select, vim, highlight, vimgrep

Using `:vimgrep`, inside Vim, in normal mode I can type:

```
:vimgrep mywords %
```

to search for "mywords" in the documents below the current directory.

But I wish that in normal mode, when I highlight a word using `gd`, or in visual mode use `viw` to select a word, I use a hot key <kbd>F8</kbd> to vimgrep. So I add in my `vimrc` and restart Vim:

```
vnoremap <F8> :vimgrep expand('<cword>') %<CR>
```

This doesn't work for me. I put focus on one word and select it, I press <kbd>F8</kbd>, no response in Vim. How can I make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
vnoremap <F8> y:vimgrep "<c-r>"" %<CR>
```

- [`:h y`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#yank)
- [`:h <C-r>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-R)

Recommended reading: [Mapping keys in Vim - Tutorial (Part 1)](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1))

Comment: Thanks it works, just with to know why there are 2 " signs, not just 1 sign

Comment: If you remove the outer `"` you're left with `<c-r>"`, which inserts the contents of register `"` (the contents of the last delete/yank). That's why there are two `"`

Answer (score 6):

Vimscript is evaluated exactly like the Ex commands typed in the `:` command-line. There were no variables in `ex`, so there's no way to specify them. When typing a command interactively, you'd probably use `<C-R>=` to insert variable contents:

```
:vimgrep <C-R>=expand('<cword>')<CR> '%'<CR>
```

... but in a script, `:execute` must be used. All the literal parts of the Ex command must be quoted (single or double quotes), and then concatenated with the variables:

```
execute 'vimgrep' expand('<cword>') '%'
```

Actually, there's a built-in command for inserting the current word into the command-line: `:help c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W`:

```
:vimgrep <C-R><C-W>
```

#### Your mapping

You could use all three approaches; let's use the last:

```
vnoremap <F8> :<C-u>vimgrep <C-r><C-w> %<CR>
```

The `<C-u>` clears the `'<,'>` range that is automatically inserted.

#### What you probably wanted

Using the current word from visual mode is strange. You probably wanted to search for the current selection. There's no `expand()` for that. Easiest is to `y`ank, as outlined by @ryuichiro's answer:

```
vnoremap <F8> y:vimgrep /<C-r>"/ %<CR>
```

Still missing is escaping of the literal text (`:vimgrep` searches for a regular expression pattern), and of the `/` delimiter:

```
vnoremap <F8> y:execute 'vimgrep /\V' . escape(@@, '/\') . '/ %'<CR>
```

#### Robust plugin solution

Now, if you also want to avoid the clobbering of the default register, it gets really complicated. Have a look at my [GrepHere plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4191); it provides a `{Visual}<A-M>` mapping for exactly that.

Comment: Beautiful answer:-)